# How to implement background task scheduling via cron jobs in .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, cron

I want to create a dynamic cron job (background tasks should not be affected if application server goes down), based on every request, and the cron job can be rescheduled or deleted. How can I implement this in .NET Core?

Comment: Too broad, will result in opinionated answers and generally off-topic

Comment: This is a very broad topic. What requests are these you mention? Rescheduled or deleted how? Why not use an actual scheduler?

Comment: Best way for *what*? What are the requirements? The documentation page for [hosted background services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-2.1#timed-background-tasks) itself contains a timer example. More advanced solutions include Hangfire and Quartz.NET. There are other solutions too

Comment: As for `background tasks should not be affected if application server goes down` then don't use the application server for that job, use the scheduler provided by your OS or database, eg `cron` on Linux, Task Scheduler on Windows, SQL Server Agent if you target SQL Server

Comment: Are you looking for a *distributed* scheduler perhaps? That's a far more complex problem

Comment: Any source which i can take as a reference.

Comment: Create a completely normal console application, no magic, just make it do what you need to do when scheduled. Then use the built-in scheduler in whatever server you host the application in to schedule it. Both Windows, Linux and macOS has these mechanisms. Don't reinvent something if you don't have to.

Answer (score 6):

Create a new .NET Core console application and use the below template in your Program.cs inside the main method (using C# 7):

```
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
{  
    var builder = new HostBuilder()
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
        {
        // i needed the input argument for command line, you can use it or simply remove this block
            config.AddEnvironmentVariables();

            if (args != null)
            {
                config.AddCommandLine(args);
            }

            Shared.Configuration = config.Build();
        })
        .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
        {
            // dependency injection
      
            services.AddOptions();
           // here is the core, where you inject the
           services.AddSingleton<Daemon>();
           services.AddSingleton<IHostedService, MyService>();
        })
        .ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, logging) => {
           // console logging 
            logging.AddConfiguration(hostingContext.Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
            logging.AddConsole();
        });

    await builder.RunConsoleAsync();
}
```

Here is the daemon/service code

```
public class MyService: IHostedService, IDisposable
   {
       private readonly ILogger _logger;
       private readonly Daemon _deamon;

       public MyService(ILogger<MyService> logger, Daemon daemon /* and probably the rest of dependencies*/)
       {
           _logger = logger;         
           _daemon = daemon;  
       }

       public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
       {
           await _deamon.StartAsync(cancellationToken);
       }

       public async Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
       {
           await _deamon.StopAsync(cancellationToken);
       }

       public void Dispose()
       {
           _deamon.Dispose();
       }
}
```

and here is the core, what you want to do,the below code is a **template and you must provide the correct implementation**:

```
public class Daemon: IDisposable
   {
       private ILogger<Daemon> _logger;
        
      
       protected TaskRunnerBase(ILogger<Daemon> logger)
       {
          _logger = logger;
       }
        
       public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
       {            
           while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
           {
                await MainAction.DoAsync(cancellationToken); // main job 
            }
       }

       public async Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
       {
           await Task.WhenAny(MainAction, Task.Delay(-1, cancellationToken));
           cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
       }

       public void Dispose()
       {
            MainAction.Dispose();
       }
}
```

1. You can run it on both Windows and Linux since you're using .NET Core
2. My .NET Core version is 2.1.